# How to prevent useCallback from triggering when using with useEffect (and comply with eslint-plugin-react-hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I have a use-case where a page have to call the same fetch function on first render and on button click.

*The code is similar to the below (ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-bink-62951987?file=index.tsx):*

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchBackend } from './fetchBackend';

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>('a');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const query = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      const res = await fetchBackend(selected);
      setData(res);
      setError(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    query();
  }, [query])

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={e => setSelected(e.target.value)} value={selected}>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
      </select>
      <div>
        <button onClick={query}>Query</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      {loading ? <div>Loading</div> : <div>{data}</div>}
      {error && <div>Error</div>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The problem for me is the fetch function always triggers on any input changed because `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` forces me to declare all dependencies (ex: selected state) in the `useCallback` hook. And I have to use `useCallback` in order to use it with `useEffect`.

I am aware that I can put the function outside of the component and passes all the arguments (props, setLoading, setError, ..etc.) in order for this to work but I wonder whether it is possible to archive the same effect while keeping the fetch function inside the component and comply to `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`?

---

[UPDATED]
For anyone who is interested in viewing the working example. Here is the updated code derived from the accepted answer.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-bink-62951987-vxqtwm?file=index.tsx

Comment: How do you protect against memory leaks with this approach? If a user navigates away from the page before the response comes back, you've not protected yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add all of your dependecies to `useCallback` as usual, but don't make another function in useEffect:

`useEffect(query, [])`

**For async callbacks** (like query in your case), you'll need to use the old-styled promise way with `.then`, `.catch` and `.finally` callbacks in order to have a void function passed to `useCallback`, which is required by `useEffect`.

Another approach can be found on [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback), but it's not recommended according to the docs.

After all, inline functions passed to `useEffect` are re-declared on each re-render anyways. With the first approach, you'll be passing new function only when the deps of query change. The warnings should go away, too. ;)

Comment: Thank you for showing me the possible approaches. The `useEffect(query, [])` looks great to me but when I tried to use it with my code, the typescript gives me an error (see https://imgur.com/a/tP0Lvp0.) because the `useEffect` does not accept the type '() => Promise<void>'.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that it's async. In this case you can avoid that error if you use the old-style approach with ```.then```, ```.catch``` and ```.finally``` on the promise. With that, you won't be returning a promise, anymore.

Comment: I tried the old-style approach at https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-bink-vxqtwm. But, when the select component changed, it still triggers re-render. Did I miss anything?

Comment: You haven't replaced the effect with ```useEffect(query, [])``` You also no longer need the ```async``` keyword in front of query function.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have updated the code and it worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you protect against memory leaks with this approach? If a user navigates away from the page before the response comes back, you've not protected yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few models to achieve something where you need to call a *fetch function* when a component *mounts* and on a *click* on a button/other. Here I bring to you another model where you achieve both by using *hooks* only and without calling the *fetch function* directly based on a button click. It'll also help you to satisfy *eslint rules for hook deps array* and be safe about infinite loop easily. Actually, this will leverage the power of effect hook called `useEffect` and other being `useState`. But in case you have multiple functions to fetch different data, then you can consider many options, like *useReducer* approach. Well, look at this project where I tried to achieve something similar to what you wanted.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-data-in-react-hooks-23q1k?file=/src/App.js

### Let's talk about the model a bit

```js
export default function App() {
  const [data, setDate] = React.useState("");
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);
  const [url, setUrl] = React.useState(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`
  );
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setDate(json);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Fetch data from API in React Hooks</h1>
      <input value={id} type="number" onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          setUrl(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`);
        }}
      >
        GO & FETCH
      </button>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading</p>
      ) : (
        <pre>
          <code>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I fetched data in first rendering using the initial link, and on each button click instead of calling any method I updated a state that exists in the deps array of effect hook, `useEffect`, so that `useEffect` runs again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the desired behavior easily as

```
useEffect(() => {
    query();
  }, [data]) // Only re-run the effect if data changes
```

For details, navigate to the end of this [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) page.

Comment: Thank for your response. I have tried it and I think this approach cause the fetch function to be called twice. The first time when data is null (not fetched yet) and the second time the when data exists.

Comment: The eslint also throw an error `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'query'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`.