# React useEffect has missing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi there i'm new to react i'm setting state and city using pincode when it has length of 6 digits when i put whole function inside useEffect it gives error to include setPersonalDetState & i also want to use same funtion to validate i cannot include it inside useEffect

```
const intialState = {
  city: '',
  state: '',
  pincode: ''
};

const PersonalDetails = () => {
  const [personalDetState, setPersonalDetState] = useState(intialState);

  const { city, state, pincode } = personalDetState;

  const fetchPincode = async (pincode) => {
    if (pincode.length != 6) {
      return;
    }
    let cityState = await axios.get(
      `https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${pincode}`
    );
    const { Status, PostOffice } = cityState.data[0];

    const { District, State } = PostOffice[0];
    personalDetState['city'] = District;
    personalDetState['state'] = State;
    return setPersonalDetState({ ...personalDetState });
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPincode(pincode);
  }, [pincode]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let { value, name } = event.target;
    
    if (name === 'pincode') value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (name === 'pincode' && value.length === 7) return;

    setPersonalDetState({ ...personalDetState, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='pincode'
        value={pincode}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input type='text' name='city' value={city} disabled />
      <input type='text' name='state' value={state} disabled />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `useCallback` for `fetchPincode` in order to correctly specify it as a dependency to the effect. It will run whenever pincode changes, but since fetchPincode callback doesn't have dependencies, it won't trigger the effect.

```
const intialState = {
  city: '',
  state: '',
  pincode: ''
};

const PersonalDetails = () => {
  const [personalDetState, setPersonalDetState] = useState(intialState);

  const { city, state, pincode } = personalDetState;

  const fetchPincode = useCallback(() => {
    if (pincode.length != 6) {
      return;
    }
    
    axios.get(
      `https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${pincode}`
    ).then(cityState => {
        const { Status, PostOffice } = cityState.data[0];

        const { District, State } = PostOffice[0];
        setPersonalDetState(prev => ({
           city: District,
           state: State
        }));
    });
  }, [pincode]);
  
  useEffect(fetchPincode, [pincode]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let { value, name } = event.target;
    
    if (name === 'pincode') value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (name === 'pincode' && value.length === 7) return;

    setCredentials({ ...userCredentials, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='pincode'
        value={pincode}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input type='text' name='city' value={city} disabled />
      <input type='text' name='state' value={state} disabled />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I've rewritten the fetchPincode to use the old-fashion Promise syntax, because it must not return anything in order to be used as useEffect callback. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951987/how-to-prevent-usecallback-from-triggering-when-using-with-useeffect-and-comply/62952152#62952152).

**Why `useCallback`?** In order to keep the same function reference between re-renders. Reference to the function will change if its dependencies change (dependencies are specified as array right after the function, as second parameter to useCallback).

**Why the same function reference?** Because if included as a dependency to another hook (say `useEffect`), changing reference may cause the effect to re-run (in case of effects), which is probably not desired if that function reference changes too often.

**In your particular case**, `pincode` will change whenever you type (not 100% sure, but I assume `setCredentials` is doing that, I didn't see its declaration). This will cause the function reference to `fetchPincode` to change. If specified as a dependency to an effect, the effect would run if the function ref changes. **But you also have `pincode` specified as dependency so effect would run on each key input anyway.** But you might think about making the request after specified period of inactivity (user not typing), also known as **debounce**.

To learn about hooks:

- [Introducing hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
- [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html)

Comment: i'm getting React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'personalDetState'

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the version of ```setPersonalDetState``` with function taking previous state. That way you no longer need ```personalDetState``` as a dependency.

Comment: ok i got it. i have to spread all prev state thanks man, can u explain what is missing dependency when and what to use, how can i get to know in short or any source i can't get it in react documentation

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it's clear enough. ;)